# adding sudo permissions to NIS clienadding sudo permissions to NIS clients

Tags: server, permissions, sudo, nfs

I've configured a couple of ubuntu 12.04 servers with NFS and NIS like it was described in

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNISHowTo and in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

It works great, and I can login to the NIS/NFS-clients and my home directory gets loaded. Unfortunately it is not possible to gain sudo permissions on these clients, while the same user has sudo-permissions on the NIS-Master-Server.

Transferring the Master-Servers /etc/sudoers file to the clients did not work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, by simply adding

```
   d-i     network-console/start   select  continue
```

to the preseed file, which causes the debian-installer to select the continue button in the start-template of network-console. My final preseed snippet looks like this:

```
  d-i     preseed/early_command   string  anna-install network-console
  d-i     network-console/password        password test
  d-i     network-console/password-again  password test
  d-i     network-console/start   select  continue
  d-i     netcfg/get_nameservers  string
  d-i     netcfg/get_ipaddress    string
  d-i     netcfg/get_netmask      string 255.255.255.0
  d-i     netcfg/get_gateway      string
```